# Want to build data driven framework with selenium webdriver

Tags: webdriver, test-automation-framework, selenium-webdriver, data-driven

I have knowledge of selenium and want to implement data driven framework.
So, I need basic knowledge for this at a starting level so that I can proceed in my organization

Comment: What language are you using? Can you expand more on what exactly you are looking and where you are having problems?

Comment: I am writing in java and I am working in an ERP solution. I am able to write the scripts to automate the individual pages and but I have no idea how to manage all the individual scripts if I write many.
So, I need help in designing a framework to manage them all

Comment: I think this is too broad a question to really answer easily as it stands - SQA is a better fit for specific questions about the problems you've been running into.

Answer (score 2):

Don't start with designing framework: [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle [applies](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt). Start coding. Implement tests, refactor common parts - and framework will emerge. Difference is, this framework will have only features you need.

By definition, if you have to ask how to design a testing framework (don't already have skills to do it right), you should not try to foresee what you may need - because you cannot do it right.

Become a skilled programmer, and after trying for a while, you will see what works for your situation. Also, read code of other more skilled coders. Join some relevant open source projects.

Comment: That's a good point you are saying.  I am able to write the scripts to automate the individual pages and but I have no idea how to manage all the individual scripts if I write many. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to disagree with the comment of not designing and just coding.  As with any testing you should aim to plan and find issues in requirements Before writing code.  Its harder to change things later!

I am quite a fan of Page Object Model (POM) as an approach

http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/page-object-model-framework-introduction
http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/

This approach keeps your tests, data and page elements separate from one another. For me, this makes the tests easy write, and just as importantly, to maintain.

For example if a test fails following this model its unlikely the test conditions have changed after it initially passed.  That means the test code will probably not need changing.

Has the element moved? Update the element location
Has the data changed? Update the data

Following concepts like "one test, one assert" will also mean your errors will likely tell you exactly what needs updating to fix your tests.  Or better yet, what to raise a bug about ;)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how page objects make the test more data-driven?

Comment: In of itself no model Makes tests data-driven.  It only offers methods of managing the data.  What I suggest is the separation of elements and test data from the tests themselves.  This will make things easier to scale (among other things)

Comment: I thought i may be useful to you (and others) to create a webdriver base project on GitHub,  feel free to use it as a base for your project https://github.com/ECiurleo/webdriverBase